# Characterizing numbers satisfying simple covering property

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, integers

Let $A, B, C, D$ be positive integers. Using those numbers we produce two colorings of $\mathbb{N}$: the first one starts by coloring first $A$ numbers blue, then next $B$ numbers red and then repeat, and second starts by first coloring first $C$ numbers red and then $D$ numbers blue and so on. We say that two such colorings $\textit{intersect}$ iff there is some natural number $n$ colored by red by both of the colorings.

It is easy to see that any two colorings intersect iff they intersect below $LCM(A+B, C+D)$. My question is whether there is a reasonably simple characterization of numbers $A, B, C, D$ so that corresponding colorings $\textit{do not}$ intersect. By reasonably simple I mean better than saying something like $\forall n \leq LCM(A + B,C + D): [1 \leq n \: \text{mod}(A + B) \leq  A] \: \: \lor \: \: [C + 1 \leq n \: \text{mod}(C + D) \leq C + D - 1] \: \: \lor \: \: [n \: \text{mod}(C + D) = 0]$.

If this turns out be simple enough, then next I would like to add two new numbers $E$ and $F$ which should be treated as blue colored offsets for the two previous colorings (i.e. we first color $E$ numbers blue and then proceed with $A$ blue, $B$ red, $A$ blue, $B$ red and so on). For this scenario I am interested in $i.o. intersecting$ colorings, i.e. colorings so that $n$ witnessing intersection can be arbitrarily large. Again, the question is to find a reasonable characterization of numbers $A, B, C, D, E, F$ so that corresponding colorings $\textit{do not}$ i.o. intersect.

Comment: What do you mean by saying a coloring “starts by coloring first $A$ numbers blue”? Do you mean that each of $1, 2, \ldots, A-1$ and $A$ gets colored blue? So then $A+1, A+2, \ldots, A+B$ all get colored red? Then $A+B+1$ though $2A+B$ are colored blue, etc.?

Comment: Yes, exactly like You said.

Comment: Can you find any specific cases where they do not intersect?

Comment: Yes, e.g. pick A = 2, B = 1 and C = 1, D = 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observations towards a solution. If you're stuck, explain what you've tried.

- Step 1: Assume that $A+B = C+D$. Show that there is an intersection iff $ B+C > A+B$.

  - Like OP mentioned, it is sufficient to focus on the first $LCM(A+B, C+D) = A+B$ numbers.
  - The necessary and sufficient condition for an  intersection should be obvious. EG OP's example given in the comments.
  - Note Step 1 is actually a subcase of Step 2, but I split it out as it's easier to focus on the first crux of considering intersections.
- Step 2: Let $G = \gcd( A+B, C+D)$. Show that there is an intersection iff $B+C > G$.

  - The second crux is considering which of the $G$ numbers (out of $LCM(A+B, C+D)$) we want to focus on.
  - Hence there is an intersection when $B+C > G$.

Hence, there is no intersection iff $ B+C \leq \gcd(A+B, C+D)$.

Comment: Beautiful! This is exactly the type of characterization I've hoped to find, thank You! 

Towards the case with offsets, first thing is that you can w.l.o.g. assume that actually there is only one non-zero offset and so maybe this might make the problem easier.

I was able to come up with something in a very special case where A = C and B = D. Then there is no i.o. intersection iff (E + A) is congruent to (F + C) mod (A + B).

Do You have any references to these "cover set" ideas? This might help me a lot.

Comment: @yellowinastrip 1/ If that's what you're looking for, please upvote (and even accept) the solution. 2/ Oh, I didn't read your "with offsets" and thought that you were introducing a third sequence with first E blue and then F red. Let me have a think about it, but nothing obvious comes to mind.